# DDS Interpolation - 8bit Atmel AVR ASM to 12 bit DAC

Tags: c, assembly, embedded, microcontroller, avr

I just completed a DDS project, on an Atmel AVR employing ASM, and have come to the conclusion that an 8 bit look-up table and 8 bit DAC create too much quantization distortion at low frequencies; for lack of better wording, I'm getting a sine wave with a ladder effect on my oscilloscope.

Obviously, If I smooth out the waveform with a big LPF, I have problems with amplitude in higher frequencies.

In theory, upgrading from an 8 bit to 12 bit DAC and employing interpolation with the 4 least significant bits should allow me to raise the cutoff point of my filter a significant enough amount to alleviate problems with waveform amplitude at higher frequencies.  My problem is that I don't have a clue how to do this or if there is an easier way to remove the zipper effect.. perhaps 12 bit look-up tables?

So far, I've created an infinite loop and every time the loop completes a cycle, a value is sent to the DAC based on the position of the pointer related to the look-up table.  Here's where I get confused.  I've read tons of info on this and still haven't found a working example.  If I have an infinite loop, how am I supposed to stuff the interpolation values between the table look-up values?  About the best thing that I can think of is (a + b) /2; I can probably implement this and get an extra bit or the equivalent of a 512 point look-up table, but I'd like to think that there is an easier way or something that could potentially deliver better results.  I don't know C or how to employ it, but I will give it a try if it is prudent.

Currently, my clock is at 1MHZ and I could probably go to 16MHZ if necessary.

Here is a sample of my code:

; Set sinewave output as default

```
    ldi     ZH, High(sine*2); setup Z pointer hi
    ldi     ZL, Low(sine*2) ; setup Z pointer lo
```

; Clear accumulator

```
    clr     r29             ; clear accumulator
```

; Setup adder registers

```
    ldi     r24,0x50        ; Fine adder value change register
    ldi     r25,0x08        ; Middle adder value change register
    ldi     r26,0x00        ; Coarse adder value change register
```

LOOP1:

```
    add     r28,r24         ; 1  Adder values carry over to higher registers.  Higher registers raise freq. in larger steps 
    adc     r29,r25         ; 1
    adc     r30,r26         ; 1  r30 is database address pointer for Z register
    lpm     r0, Z           ; 3  (Load Program Memory) Reads byte from database into the destination register based on Z pointer
    out     PORTD,r0


    rjmp    LOOP1           ; 2 => 9 cycles
```

Answer (score 2):

If your LUT has 256 entries, you can first use the register r29 (that apparently goes from 0 to 255) as the scaling factor between two successive samples.

`Output = (LUT[r30] * (256 - r29) + LUT[r30+1] * r29) >> 8;`

[Also this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466623/how-to-look-up-sine-of-different-frequencies-from-a-fixed-sized-lookup-table) discusses many practical alternatives to sine wave generation.

**EDIT** The formula implements text book linear interpolation

```
y = a*(1-t) + b*t, with 0<=t<1
```

So that y=a, when t=0 and y=b, when t=1. Shifting by 8 means that the interpolation term *t* is divided by 256 after the multiplication. In the expression LUT[r30+1] I'm assuming an implicit modulo 256 arithmetic, as r30 is 8-bit (isn't it?).

LUT expansion to 12 bit has to be done separately, as dividing by 4 instead would just increase the quantization error in the LUT.

[image]

The interpolation happens always relative to integer indices in the LUT, regardless if many samples fall to the same range eg. LUT[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVkmK.gif) and LUT[3]. Mathematically Lut[R], LUT[R+1] is more correct than [R-1], [R], but in real life there is no difference, as human audatory system doesn't have absolute reference phase.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I don't understand it though.  Why shift right 8 bits?  The first part of the equation could very easily overflow the registers.   Wouldn't LUT[r30+1] change the phase of the waveform, not advance to the next time sensitive step of the pointer?  Wouldn't it make more sense to query the previous pointer step?